# How to upgrade inventory slots, ship & multi-tool in No Man's Sky on creative mode?

Tags: no-mans-sky

My 7yo has started playing "No Man's Sky" in creative mode. They treat it like Minecraft in space - exploring, mining, finding creatures, blowing holes in things etc.

However the lack of inventory space still seems to be an issue in creative mode with a very limited number of slots. Which is very frustrating.

And the multi-tool & ship only seem to have very basic upgrades available.

Is it possible to upgrade the inventory slots, ship & multi-tool in creative mode to their maximum levels without having to go through the normal survival gameplay (i.e. finding drop pods etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No- you will still have to go through the normal method of acquiring exosuit upgrades in creative. That means finding drop pods, interacting with NPCs, etc. A few examples of how to get inventory upgrades just as a reference:

- Visiting space stations w/ Atlas Pass
- Finding drop/escape pods on planets
- Finding broken ships on planets

Multi-tool upgrades are also acquired in the same way in creative as survival. You may find better multi-tools on the interior walls of buildings, or in NPC interactions.

Answer (score -1):

You can expand quite easily your exosuit inventory :

- Go to a space station
- Go to seethe exosuit tech merchant, the farthest from the stair
- Don't talk to him (or talk to him if you like him), but instead look at the backpack hologram behind him

You'll can buy 1 slot by 1 slot from each station, begininng at 10.000 units only.

Expanding your multi-tool (if it is even possible) won't be useful as you can only stock technologies.
And for the ship, a lot of players says you can't expand, while I've seen mine got granted one more slot... And I event don't know how this happened ^^'